# privnote.com - Note encryption not able to be decrypted by admin?

Tags: php, security, encryption, laravel

I had a question concerning these "secure" one time note sites such as https://privnote.com.

It appears that when you create a note, Privnote provides a one time use URL that has a key to unlock the note. Once the URL is requested the note is destroyed.

Their Privacy Policy states:

> Since only the link binds the decryption key to the note's content and
>   since Privnote does not have the link, at no time is any note held in
>   any readable format state at Privnote. This assures that nobody
>   (including Privnote's administrators) can read a note.

My question is, how could Privnote store the seemingly 2-way encryption of a note that not even an admin could decrypt? I ask because I'm trying to build something similar within the Laravel framework which uses PHPs mCrypt. I see no way to store an encrypted piece of info that I cannot decrypt.

Thank you.

Comment: Better to be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com , I think.

Comment: Put the key in the url fragment and decrypt on the client. Obviously you could still deliver evil javascript to the client, but that's a fundamental limitation of web applications.

Answer (score -1):

The following post explains the method of action and transmission: http://wonko.com/post/privnotes-developers-are-either-stupid-or-malicious

Excerpt:

> As it turns out, they are indeed encrypting notes using cleartext note ids and then only storing the hashed id in the database. This ensures that someone in possession of the database cannot recover the note ids and thus cannot decrypt the notes, and is a much better implementation than the one described in the original post. However it still doesn’t guarantee that Privnote’s developers aren’t executing additional code to intercept notes before they’re encrypted.

Also, you may want to look into PGP vs Privnote as it doesn't depend on the integrity of a third party.
Or just go back to the old ways of pen and paper. Can't track that electronically, but can of course be intercepted, can still use code though and it is a much less scrutinised service data wise as electronic transmission. Just be careful with licking your DNA all over it.
Or just be a good, honest, no-privacy-to-violate humanbot. ;-)